# Delete from GCS without exception if file is not present

Tags: linux, shell, google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I'm calling a shell script through python.

Inside the script I'm using `gsutil rm` and `gsutil cp` commands.

But whenever any of these 2 commands run on a gcp path, which is not present, it gives error.

For eg: When i try:

```
gsutil rm -r gs://some-bucket/somepath-not-present/
```

I get an error :

```
CommandException: 1 files/objects could not be removed.
```

And in the end the return code of script is 1. Even though my code would have executed fine. I wanted the script to not give error when path is not found.

Is there any way to bypass this. I have tried the `||` from linux, but it doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "not get any exception"? Do you mean just continue on in a shell script despite the error? Or just not printing the error message? Or something else?

Comment: I'm running a series of shell commands, written in a script, which is called through python. It has `'gsutil rm'` and `'cp'` commands. But I  don't want the script to return 1, if it is the case when path doesn't exist. Will i have to handle the error inside the script, to make it return 0 ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the `gsutil` inside another script that may be affected by the exceptions printed by `gsutil`, you can simply try redirecting the stderr into /dev/null like this:

```
gsutil rm -r gs://some-bucket/somepath-not-present/ 2> /dev/null
```

However, beware that you will start ignoring any errors generated by the command at this point. If you `echo $?`, you will still get the error code of `1` which can tell you either the file didn't exist or other exception happened.

EDIT:

If you want to exit from the script with an exit code 0, you could do

```
gsutil rm -r gs://some-bucket/somepath-not-present/ || exit 0
```

Or if you just want the command to return 0, you could use

```
gsutil rm -r gs://some-bucket/somepath-not-present/ || true
```

Comment: This might sound silly. But is there anyway to get return code as 0, if path doesn't exist. Actually I'm running a series of shell commands, written in a script, which is called through python. I don't want the script to return 1, if it is the case when path doesn't exist.

Comment: @ezvine you can always add `|| exit 0` to the end of this line to exit with 0 (success) in case the `gsutil rm` fails with 1

Comment: Would that cause to exit from whole script. Or would only apply to that particular command in the script. i.e, would rest of the script  execute as normal ?

Comment: Oh yes - if that's not the only command you are running, you need to append `|| true` instead of the exit command. That should continue the script

Comment: Thank you verymuch. This thing worked.. Please add his to your answer..

Answer (score 1):

It's surprising to me that Google hasn't fixed this issue yet. I've had the same issue, where I was dependent on a build script to continue running, even though the bucket was already empty.

I came up with the following work around:

```
if [[ $(gsutil du gs://my-bucket | wc -l) -gt 0 ]]; then gsutil -m rm -rf gs://my-bucket/*; fi
```

It basically counts the number of objects in the bucket and only runs `gsutil rm` if the count is larger than zero.

Comment: i dont think doing a complete du will be a good idea if number of files inside the folder is very large.
It would be a time consuming command. `|| true` is a good option as suggested in above answer.
Or maybe try a `gsutil ls gs://my-bucket | head -1 | wc -l` and only if this command is success and >1, then remove the files.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point. In our case the number of files of the source folder, rarely would be very large, so I didn't really consider performance to be honest. I tried the `|| true` solution, but I use it in a build pipeline, and it still caused the build script to fail. I needed a solution that would allow the script to continue.